# Scanning image word by word using Tesseract OCR for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, tesseract

Right now, I am using TesseractOCR for iOS to scan images and convert them into text. I want to be able to find a word a highlight it in the original image, so I am thinking to scan the document word by word and look for the phrase or word passed in by the user. However, I can't find any resources on the tesseractOCR website that point me in this direction. So basically, I am looking to scan an image word by word so I can find a phrase. I need to be able to highlight the word on the original image which is why I think i should be should scan the original image word by word. Is there any way I can scan the original image word by word using tesseractOCR (probably involving detecting whitespace)? If so any relevant resources would be helpful. If I can't use tesseractOCR should I be using something else or is it not possible at all?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

TesseractOCR for iOS has an api call which returns [recognized blocks by iterator level](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/TesseractOCRiOS/4.0.0/Classes/G8Tesseract.html#//api/name/recognizedBlocksByIteratorLevel:). You can set the iterator level to G8PageIteratorLevelWord to obtain words.

What's also important is that each recognized block has [boundingBox](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/TesseractOCRiOS/4.0.0/Classes/G8RecognizedBlock.html) property, which points directly to the location of the block on the image. You can use this for highlighting the word on the image.

If, after this, you want to find some specific phrase or word in obtained set of words, you will have to be a little more creative :) OCR results can contain errors, so you can use exact string matching, but fuzzy matching. Also, searching phrases (as opposed to searching just words), opens questions of layouting OCR results, because words in one phrase aren't always adjacent in OCR result.

Note: my company [MicroBlink](https://microblink.com) offes commercial [OCR engine](https://github.com/blinkocr) for mobile devices. On iOS you can easily try it using cocoapods

```
pod try PPBlinkOCR
```

BlinkOCR solves all of the problems above, and you can contact us for support while you use it.